# Soft Question: Introductory books on Algebraic Number Theory

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, algebraic-number-theory

I am a high school student in Britain. I have recently studied elementary number theory and absolutely loved it. I got as far as to prove results like quadratic reciprocity, Fermat's sum of two squares, and Bertrand's postulate, and I would like to progress further.

From what I can see, it seems like the next steps are beginning to read about algebraic or analytic number theory. I don't have a firm base in complex analysis as I'm only in high school, and so would like to begin reading about algebraic number theory.

Are there any books you would recommend, for someone only with a vague set of notions of the definitions of algebraic structures (Groups, Rings, Fields)?

I do understand that there are a couple of questions asking something similar, but the books recommended there seem to be for someone of a higher mathematical level than me currently (e.g someone with a maths degree).

Any attention on this would be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Attempting to learn algebraic number theory without first learning rudimentary abstract algebra is like trying to learn to run before you've learned to walk.

Comment: I second what @BillDubuque says. You should read some introductory texts on the algebraic structures you list first. A First Course in Abstract Algebra by John Fraleigh is a standard recommendation to get a good basic understanding of groups, rings and fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For understanding algebraic number fields, a good deal of algebra, in particular Galois theory, is indispensible. This being said I learned algebraic number theory before algebra. This forces you to restrict to
quadratic and perhaps cyclotomic number fields (the Galois theory for such
fields was worked out already by Gauss). There are many introductions to quadratic number fields out there; if I recall it correctly, there are also a few sections on quadratic number fields in the classical textbook by Hardy and Wright as well as in the book "A Journey Through The Realm of Numbers" by Aka et al., which was written for an audience without a background in algebra.
Chapters V - VIII in Legh Wilber Reid's [book](https://ia600904.us.archive.org/7/items/elementsoftheory00reidrich/elementsoftheory00reidrich.pdf) presents the arithmetic of ${\mathbb Q}(i)$, ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{-3})$, ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ (the language is a little bit outdated) before starting the general theory.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; I'll try looking through the material suggested.